# Updating Nginx on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-14.04

Is it possible to update it on this version of Ubuntu?
As when I’m trying

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable
```

It says

```
**Only Non-End-of-Life Ubuntu Releases are supported in this PPA**
```

And

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install nginx
```

Says “nginx is already the newest version.” Even it is 1.4.6

Comment: that PPA does not support 14.04 anymore, this is why you can't upgrade nginx using these commands. As you wrote, Only Non-End-of-Life ubuntu releases are supported. 14.04 reached end of life on 30.04.2019

Comment: @Stefano is there an alternative way to upgrade it?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not worth the time. The newer versions of nginx require openssl>=1.0.2 and I didn't manage to find any backport for this package. Depending on how you use nginx, you may think about a cointeinerized solution but it depends on how does your architecture looks like. I've tried to create a ubuntu14.04 vagrant image but I haven't got much luck.